# Fastest C/C++ technique for sending data across network?

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, kernel

If I have two Linux boxes and I am writing a C/C++ program to send a message on one box and receive on the other box, what is the fastest approach?

I am not sure if the various socket/networking technologies I hear banded around are simply wrappers around an underlying technology, or if they are alternative possibilities. I just want to know what would be the closest to "bare metal" which I could implement from my application.

I was thinking the fastest method would including writing my program as a driver and load this into the kernel. However, I would still need to know the fastest socket implementation to use with this idea.

Comment: There are some pretty obvious choices here, such as TCP. What are some of the "various socket/networking technologies" to which you refer?

Comment: Fastest or most reliable delivery?

Comment: I guess it comes down to how fast is "fast"? TCP isn't realtime, but a wired GB connection between 2 boxes sitting next to each other is pretty dang fast. I suppose if you *need* fast and realtime, you probably want to get them both on the same PCI/PCIe bus. I've used that in realtime industrial contexts, but I wouldn't want to mess with that unless I had to ;-0

Comment: Just use standard userspace UDP functions.  IMO, the difference you *may* see by hacking the networking stack will be negligible compared to the amount of time you'll end up spending on it.  If you don't need routing, maybe raw sockets is a consideration, but again the savings will be negligible.

Comment: @GregHewgill Berkely Sockets, non-Berkely Sockets, TCP sockets, UDP sockets etc

Comment: My guess is you're going to waste a bunch of time trying to overoptimize.  The amount of extra development and maintenance of trying to go "bare metal" will almost certainly yield no significant gain, and definitely much less bang for the buck than just buying a faster machine.

Comment: @jedwards I understand Linux uses nagler's algorithm which if removed could cause significant gains in throughput? This is why I am thinking of writing my own driver.

Comment: I don't think the Nagle algorithm is used for UDP, only for TCP.  But even in TCP you can disable it with `setsockopt` and `TCP_NODELAY`.

Comment: What's "fast"? Low latency or high throughput? How big is your data?

Comment: If you're going to all this bother implement RDMA.  There are some off the shelf (but expensive) solutions.

Comment: What specialized hardware do you have? If you have only a plain ethernet connection don't bother too much about optimizing (but do use big, ie. 8Kbytes chunks in your `recv` and `send` syscalls). With plain Ethernet (even gigabit/sec ethernet) the bottleneck is the hardware....

Answer (score 3):

Any modern PC will be able to keep the ethernet chip buffers fully loaded so "bare metal" programming will provide no benefit.  The added latency through the kernel is so small compared to the network latency (i.e. speed of light limitations) that it's not worth optimizing.

For "fast" as in high-bandwidth data-moving between two connected Linux boxes, TCP is your friend as it will optimize itself to the maximum network ability without you having to detect and adjust yourself.  Direct connect will have negligible packet-loss and generally low latency so you don't have to worry about window sizes, etc.

If you want "fast" as in quick turnaround to small requests, use UDP.

If you have some other definition of "fast", well, you need to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

The question is incomplete, as you do not specify any requirements except that it must be fast. There are lots of aspects to consider here, such as the protocol to use (TCP for reliability, UDP for streaming, etc), serialization (what kind of data do you plan to send over the network, can you use a serialization library such as Google Protobuf?), and so on.

My suggestion would be to have a look at various RPC frameworks such as Apache Thrift, Apace Etch or ZeroC Ice and benchmark them before you decide that you really need to use tbe BSD sockets API or a similar low level abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Well, unless you want to build a kernel module for custom communications over Ethernet, the fastest userspace API from libc is the Berkley Sockets API. Yes, that is a wrapper over the kernels TCP/IP and UDP/IP, which is a layer over IP, which is a layer of WWAN, LAN, and Ethernet, which is a layer over something else, but unless you need such incredible and exact performance, I suggest staying in the simple stuff in userland rather then writing the kernel modules you'd need to use anything lower. Unless I'm completely wrong, there is no way to access raw Ethernet, WWAN, or LAN from userspace, let alone actually accessing the hardware.

Note: If you have a few years to rewrite the entire UNIX networking stack and networking card drivers, you can get x86 I/O port access from userspace when running as root with the `ioperm()` call, but I don't suggest rewriting the entire UNIX networking stack. That's almost 2 decades of work. Also, direct hardware access from a 3-d party application is a security disaster waiting to happen.

Note: If you are OK with not using any traditional *hardware* for networking, you could write a custom driver for double ended USB cables and create a custom network protocol over that, as writing Linux USB device drivers is probably the easiest kind of driver to write, as there is a large API for it. I really don't know how the speed will stack up here though, as USb 2.0 is faster then older Ethernet standards, but then they are starting to have 1 Gbps Ethernet, be now there's SUB 3.0, so this could be faster or slower, depending on available hardware. This is more about ease of use.

EDIT: Please, never, ever, ever put code in the kernel for the sake of speed. Please. The huge security hole you put in a machine is not worth the small boost in performance. There was a time when system calls were very expensive, and you wanted to minimize and adding to the kernel was an option, but with newer standards like Intel's `sysenter`/`sysexit`, and AMD's `syscall`/`sysret`, they are cheep enough to not warrant the security hole.